# Caching options for php script that pulls data from mysql tables

Tags: php, html, mysql, caching

I wanted to know what function to use to cache the data that is pulled and refresh it only after 15-30 minutes.

Here's the php script that pulls data from mysql to website.

```
<?php
include('mysql_connection.php');

$c = mysqlConnect();

$locale = $_GET['locale'];
$last_bulletins_id = $_GET['bulletins_id'];

sendQuery ("set character_set_results='utf8'"); 
sendQuery ("set collation_connection='utf8_general_ci'"); 

if(strcmp($locale,"en") != 0)
$locale = "en";
$result = sendQuery("
SELECT bulletins.id, posted_date, message, name
FROM bulletins 
LEFT JOIN players ON (bulletins.player_id = players.user_id)
WHERE bulletins.id > ".$last_bulletins_id." and locale = '".$locale."' 
ORDER BY bulletins.id DESC 
LIMIT 10");
echo '<table width=\"100%\">';
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM))
{
    echo '<tr><td width=\"100%\"><b>Date: </b>'.$row[1].'</td></tr>';
    echo '<tr><td width=\"100%\"><b>Author: </b>'.$row[3].'</td></tr>';
    echo '<tr><td width=\"100%\">'.nl2br($row[2]).'</td></tr>';
    echo '<tr><td width=\"100%\"><hr style="height: 2px; border: none; background: #515151;"></td></tr>';
}
echo '</table>';    

mysqlClose($c);
```

?>

Answer (score 0):

You should write data that you output in cache file and check how much time has passed from last modification of file and load cache file or query the database and output new results if time is greater than the limit you set. These functions will come handy to you:

[file-put-contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php)

[filemtime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filemtime.php)

[touch](http://php.net/manual/en/function.touch.php)

[file-exists](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php)